# Is there a difference in #submit handlers when called through node forms rather than system_settings_forms?

Tags: 7, caching

I have a custom admin backend form where an editor can choose an "Active Header" for the entire site. Each header is a custom entity that stores certain values, such as the current logo, a primary color, and a base color.

I have the exact same #submit handler on both the custom admin form and set on `hook_form_alter()` for the Header entity.

Here is the code for the submit handler.

```
/**
 * Flushes header cache whenever a header is updated.
 */
function MYMODULE_clear_header_cache($form, &$form_state) {
  cache_clear_all('MYMODULE_header', MYMODULE_CACHE, TRUE);
  drupal_set_message('Header cache cleared.');
}
```

It is invoked on both the header form submit and the custom form submit, but the cache only actually clears when invoked on the custom form. When editing the header, it is necessary to submit the custom form before changes take effect, even though the exact same code runs in both cases (`drupal_set_message()` displays the message in both cases).

Can anyone please explain to me what's happening? I have tried everything I can think of, and the only surefire solution I can find is removing all caching on the header (which is definitely not desirable in my instance).

To preempt any answers I have already tried:

- Yes I am using `node_load()` to obtain the header and render it into a block. I am resetting the node cache when calling `node_load()` (`node_load($my_nid, NULL, TRUE)`).
- I have completely disabled block level caching on the header block.  It shouldn't make a difference considering the cache clears just fine from the custom form, but I tried it anyways.
- I have tried using `db_truncate(MYMODULE_CACHE)->execute();` to no avail.

So it seems that my header is getting cached elsewhere. Is there something special about `system_settings_form()` that flushes ALL drupal caches after submission?

Here is the full block rendering function.

```
/**
 * Builds main header.
 */
function MYMODULE_main_header() {
  $cid = 'MYMODULE_header:main';
  if ($cached = cache_get($cid, MYMODULE_CACHE)) {
    $header = $cached->data;
  }
  else {
    $header = array();
    $active_header = variable_get('MYMODULE_default_header');
    $node = node_load($active_header, NULL, TRUE);
    $alt =  t('My Site Name');
    // This is a helper function to add necessary punctuation to color values so they are usable as inline styles.
    $header['color'] = MYMODULE_fetch_primary(TRUE);
    $logo = array(
      'path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'],
      'width' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['width'],
      'height' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['height'],
      'alt' => $alt,
      'title' => $alt,
      'attributes' => array('style' => 'background-color: ' . $header['color']),
    );
    $image = theme_image($logo);
    $header['logo'] = l($image, '<front>', array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('style' => 'background-color: ' . $header['color'])));
    // A helper function to generate the nav menu.
    $header['menu'] = MYMODULE_top_menu();
    $header['dimension'] = $logo['width'] > 185 ? 'long' : 'tall';
    cache_set($cid, $header, MYMODULE_CACHE, CACHE_TEMPORARY);
  }
  // I keep forgetting forms break when they're cached.
  $search_form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_header_search_form');
  $header['search'] = drupal_render($search_form);
  return theme('MYMODULE_header', $header); 
}
```

Comment: If the code is running in both instances then there's something very fishy going on - when your submit function runs the form submission process has zero control over what happens in it. If the code's running, and the cache isn't being cleared, the form submission process isn't to blame (it just can't be). The only thing I can think is that the submit handlers for node forms are on the submit buttons (`$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']` etc), so you would probably want to attach your submit handler to those and not the form. But that doesn't explain what's happening with your code

Comment: An excellent observation, but alas it just fires the function again with no caches being cleared.

Comment: How are you getting `$my_nid`?  What exactly are you cache()ing and are you doing anything other than checking if the cid in question exists when rendering the block?  Perhaps showing some of the broad strokes in your block code might shed some more light on this.

Comment: Just a note, I have already changed the hardcoded 'und's into LANGUAGE_NONE constants.  This was preliminary code that hasn't been cleaned up yet :)